# The smallest group with 3 generators

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What is the smallest (in terms of the number of elements) nonabelian group such that any presentation requires at least 3 generators? Most of the nonabelian finite groups I know seem to require only 2 generators.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without having thought about it for long, I would guess that the smallest examples
have order 16. For example $D_8 \times C_2$ or $Q_8 \times C_2$. They have elementary abelian quotients of order 8, so they definitely need three generators.

Comment: There is only one more rank 3 group of order 16, SmallGroup(16,13), but it doesn't have as nice of a description.

Comment: Oh, and these are indeed the smallest examples just by a brute force check.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: if you don't mind clarifying, what's $\operatorname{SmallGroup}(m,n)$? I'm having a hard time finding documentation.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It is a command in GAP. The first parameter is the order of the group, the second one is an identifier for which of the groups of that order you want.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thank you!

Comment: According to this website,
 the other group satisfying these properties is [the central product of $D_8$ and $Z_4$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Central_product_of_D8_and_Z4)