# Is it true that every finite group $G$ requiring more than $2$ generators has a quotient which is an elementary abelian $p$ group of rank $3$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

An elementary abelian $ p $ group of rank 3, $ \mathbb{F}_p^3 $, requires 3 generators. As a corollary, any group with quotient $ \mathbb{F}_p^3 $ requires at least 3 generators.

What about the converse? **Is it true that every finite group $G$ requiring more than $2$ generators has a quotient which is an elementary abelian $ p $ group of rank $ 3 $?**

Is this true even more generally when $ G $ is finitely generated?

Comment: For a counterexample, take $G=S^n$ where $S$ is a finite simple nonabelian group and $n$ is chosen large enough so that $S^n$ is not $2$-generated. For this, any $n>|S|^2$ works.

Comment: You are right of course. Your answer suggests the counterexample $ A_5^{3601} $. For a somewhat smaller (but still very large) counterexample $ A_5^{20} $ is also not 2-generated see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4533999/758507. @KeithKearnes could you explain more where the condition $ n > |S|^2 $ comes from?

Comment: There is a much smaller counterexample, a group of order $18$ with elementary abelian subgroup of order $9$, and an element of order $2$ that inverts all element of order $3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Is this group the semidirect product of $ \mathbb{F}_3^2 $ by the order 2 automorphism $$ \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $$ as a matrix over $ \mathbb{F}_3 $ (just scaling by 2 which as you say inverts all elements of order 3 i.e. the 8 nonzero vectors)? Can you say more about why this group is not 2-generated? And would you be interested in posting your minimal counterexample as an answer?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira: Every $2$-generated group in the variety $V(S)$ generated by $S$ is a quotient of the $2$-generated free group in this variety. The $2$-generated free group may be constructed as the subgroup of $S^{|S|^2}$ generated by the two projection functions $\pi_1, \pi_2\colon S^2\to S\colon (x,y)\mapsto x$ or $y$. Thus, any $2$-generated group in $V(S)$ is a homomorphic image of a subgroup of $S^{|S|^2}$. If $n>|S|^2$, then $S^n$ is too big to be a hom-sub of $S^{|S|^2}$, so too big to be $2$-generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample is the group $G = N \rtimes_\phi H$ of order $18$, where $N$ is elementary abelian of order $9$,
$H = \langle t \rangle$ has order $2$, and $\phi:H \to {\rm Aut}(N)$ maps $t$ to the automorphism that sends every element of $H$ to its inverse. So $$G = \langle a,b,t \mid a^3=b^3=t^2=1, ab=ba, tat=a^{-1},tbt=b^{-1} \rangle.$$

We need to show that, for all $x,y \in G$, we have $G \ne \langle x,y \rangle$. We can assume that $x,y$ are nontrivial, so they have order $2$ or $3$.

If they both have order $3$ then they lie in $N$. If $x$ has order $2$ and $y$ has order $3$, then $xyx=y^{-1}$ and they generate a dihedral subgroup of order $6$. If they both have order $2$, then $xy$ has order $3$, and again they generate a group of order $6$. So they cannot generate $G$.

Comment: I think there is a typo the $ p $ should be a $ p^2 $ or $ 9 $ if you are specializing to $ p=3 $.

Comment: Thanks, corrected!