# Primitive permutation groups that are 2-generated

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

Let $ G $ be a primitive permutation group. Is it the case that $ G $ is 2-generated (i.e. it can be generated by two permutations)?

Note: This is false for transitive permutation groups. For example there is a degree 8 transitive permutation groups isomorphic to $ C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 $

Related question. Suppose that $ G $ is a primitive permutation group of prime degree $ p $. Must it be the case that $ G $ can be generated by a $ p $ cycle together with one other permutation? This is true for degree $ p=11 $.

EDIT: answer from ahulpke gives a degree 25 primitive group which is not 2 generated. Now the open question is whether every 2-transitive permutation group is 2-generated.

Comment: $S_n$ acts on the set of $n$ elements as a primitive permutation group. Extend this to an action by $S_n$ times your favorite group by ignoring the extra factor. The product will likely not be 2-generated.  Maybe you want $G$ to act faithfully?

Comment: @EthanDlugie a permutation group is generally defined to be a subgroup of $ S_n $ in its natural action. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group . So yes the action would be faithful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The group `PrimitiveGroup(25,11)` (called $5^2:D(2*4):2$) and generated by
$$
(6,16)(7,17)(8,18)(9,19)(10,20)(11,21)(12,22)(13,23)(14,24)(15,25),
  (2,6)(3,11)(4,16)(5,21)(8,12)(9,17)(10,22)(14,18)(15,23)(20,24),
  (1,9,17,23)(2,8,16,24)(3,6,19,22)(4,7,18,21)(5,10,20,25)(11,14,12,13)
$$
(it is not represented in minimal permutation degree) has abelianization $G/G'\cong 2\times 2\times 2$ and thus cannot be 2-generated. I would not be surprised if there was no upper bound for generating primitive groups. (E.g. `PrimitiveGroup(81,16)` is not 3-generated).

I think the claim for prime degree is true, and likely can be proven by looking at the explicit classification of groups of degree $p$, but I have not tried to do so.

Comment: Ok I'll probably just ask the prime degree question as a separate question. Is your intuition that the prime degree thing might be true even for all odd degrees? Or does that seems wrong? More important follow up question: Is every 2-transitive permutation 2-generated? GAP ( using your code from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533980/non-solvable-group-requiring-more-than-2-generators) says that answer is yes for degree $ n \leq 30 $. I imagine the answer is yes in general since simple socle groups are close to simple and simple is always 2-generated. Abelian socle case idk

Comment: The counterexample is odd degree. 2-transitive is quite likely as well (since most are close to simple)

Comment: oh oops that was dumb. Ok so ya not true for non prime degree but probably true for prime degree. Maybe I'll post the 2 transitive implies 2 generated at separate question. I checked up to degree 60 and all 2 transitive groups are 2 generated so seems pretty likely to be true

Comment: 2-transitive works up to degree 2000

Comment: lol how did you check that so fast do you have a supercomputer or are you just running way smarter code than me? Also side question is there a command in GAP that can check if a permutation group is 2-transitive? My friend Eric asked me that yesterday and I told him that if I ran into you sometime soon on MSE I would ask (I can also ask this as a separate question if you want)

Comment: No supercomputer, but one can verify 2-generated quickly by trying a couple of pairs of random elements.   And GAP has `Transitivity`. So using `OnePrimitiveGroup(NrMovedPoints,[2..2000],Transitivity,[2..2000],MyTestFunction, true)` did quickly.

Comment: I haven't done a very thorough check, but after looking through the lists of finite 2-transitive groups it looks to me as though they are all 2-generated. But an affine primitive group has an irreducible subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,p)$ as a quotient for some $n$ and prime $p$, and there is no upper bound on the minimal number of generators of such groups.