# Are transitive permutation groups of prime degree 2-generated?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

According to

[Primitive permutation groups that are 2-generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556589/primitive-permutation-groups-that-are-2-generated)

all 2-transitive permutation groups are 2-generated. There are, however, primitive groups of non prime degree, for example $ PrimitiveGroup(25,11) $ for degree $ n=25 $, which are not $ 2 $-generated.

What about for prime degree? Is it true that every transitive permutation group of prime degree is $ 2 $-generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a theorem of Burnside that a simply transitive (i.e. transitive but not 2-transitive) permutation group $G$ of prime degree $p$ has a normal subgroup $P$ of order $p$, so $G \le P \rtimes H$ with $H \le {\rm Aut}(P)$. But ${\rm Aut}(P)$ is cyclic of order $p-1$ so $G$ is $2$-generated.

Comment: ah I see so the simply transitive permutation groups of prime degree are exactly the semidirect products of the form $ p:n $ for $ n $ dividing $ p-1 $. And all the simply transitive groups of prime degree are primitive.

Comment: Yes, except that the group $p:(p-1)$ is $2$-transitive!

Comment: You're right I should have said $ n $ properly dividing $ p-1 $, that would be right!